# Ошибка не могу понять как исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот код

```
@client.command()
async def время(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = "Время" )

    emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar )
    emb.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_image(url = "")
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = '')


    now_date = datetime.now()
    emb.add_field( name = 'Time', value = 'Time: {}'.format(now_date) )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

Вот ошибка

```
Ignoring exception in command время:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Script\bot\botyara.py", line 59, in время
    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.author.icon_url: Scheme "f6740c59eac1f82fa8e1bda4f3c94cbd" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.author.icon_url: Scheme "f6740c59eac1f82fa8e1bda4f3c94cbd" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете `icon_url`, но используете `client.user.avatar`, т.е. картинку, а вам нужна ссылка.
Измените `emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar )` на `emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )`